# How to get "Storage Usage" organization information of a salesforce to another salesforce org?

Tags: api, file-storage, data-storage

I want "Storage usage" fields like data storage, field storage of a Salesforce Org to custom page of another Salesforce Org. Can anybody suggest someway around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Tooling API callout. You have 2 options, depending on how you want to store credentials.

1. "Push data": In source org (the one which storage you want to see) make the REST callout to get the data, then use some other technique (another callout? Outbound Message? Salesforce-to-Salesforce?) to post this data to target org. You don't need credentials for source org (valid Session ID is enough) but you might need credentials for target org.
2. "Pull data": From target org make a call into the source org's Tooling API.

As for the actual REST resources which you need to call:

- File storage: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_limits.htm
- Record count per object: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_api_rest.htm#rn_api_rest_record_count